# How do I build a program using two .ide files in Borland C++ 5.02?

Tags: borland-c++

I know how to get the program to build using one, but I'm not quite sure how to do get it to full build using two .IDE files.

Comment: what IDE files you have in mind (bdsproj,bpr,...)? and in what version of borland IDE (BCB1-6,BDS,RAD,XE,...)? did you mean generate 2 exe/DLL files instead?

Comment: what do those .ide files contain? What is the difference between them?